# backup mysql database java code

Tags: java, mysql, database, database-backups

I tried to run the following code which is to create a **backup of my database** but it shows some run time errors.

But, I tried to run the **System.out.println() output** part, (which I've commented in the given code) **in mysql shell and it worked**.

It shows io file problem. Plz somebody help me.

```
package files;

 public class tableBackup_1 {

public boolean tbBackup(String dbName,String dbUserName, String dbPassword, String path) {

    String executeCmd = "mysqldump -u " + dbUserName + " -p" + dbPassword + " --add-drop-database -B " + dbName + " -r " + path;
    Process runtimeProcess;
        try
        {
            System.out.println(executeCmd);//this out put works in mysql shell
            runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
            int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

                if (processComplete == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("Backup created successfully");
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Could not create the backup");
                }
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args){

        tableBackup_1 bb = new tableBackup_1();
        bb.tbBackup("test","harin","1234","C:/Users/Master/Downloads/123.sql");

}
}
```

```
    mysqldump -u harin -p1234 --add-drop-database -B test -r C:/Users/Master/Downloads/123.sql
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mysqldump": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:431)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:328)
        at files.tableBackup_1.tbBackup(tableBackup_1.java:12)
        at files.tableBackup_1.main(tableBackup_1.java:34)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:81)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:30)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: @dan Thanks dan I copied errors can u look at it and say what's wrong!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check whether your Global PATH environment variable has <Path to MySQL>\bin in it (Do a `echo %PATH%` and see). Effectively you should be able to type your System.out.println() content in a Plain DOS prompt and should be able to run it.

Even with that if it doesn't work try changing the code to execute like below

```
runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "cmd.exe", "/c", executeCmd });
```

This should ideally fix the issue.

**UPDATE:**

If you don't have it in the PATH environment variable change the code to following

```
String executeCmd = "<Path to MySQL>/bin/mysqldump -u " + dbUserName + " -p" + dbPassword + " --add-drop-database -B " + dbName + " -r " + path;
```

Comment: OMG Thank You very much It worked! Many thanks to you appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

`runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "cmd.exe", "/c", executeCmd });`

i tried this one but it didn't work so i replaced it with

`this runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);`

and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by giving full path to mysqldump.exe

You can get SO environment variables by

```
Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
final String LOCATION = env.get("MYSQLDUMP");
```

I setup the system variable like this :

- Variable Name : `MYSQLDUMP`
- Value : `D:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe`

Now just execute this code below,

```
String executeCmd = LOCATION+" -u " + DBUSER + " --add-drop-database -B " + DBNAME + " -r " + PATH + ""+FILENAME
Process runtimeProcess = = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
```

Note : If you don't have configured password for mysql server just remove the `-p PASSWORD` attribute from the code. And don't forget to restart your computer after creating a new system variable.