# Error in executing mysql command from java

Tags: java, mysql

I was trying to execute the mysql command using java but this always keeps giving error.

```
    String dbName = "dth";
    String dbUser = "root";
    String dbPass = "root";

    String executeCmd = "";
    executeCmd = "mysqldump -u " + dbUser + " -p" + dbPass + " " + dbName + " -r    C:\\backup.sql";

    Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
    int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
    if (processComplete == 0) {
        System.out.println("Backup taken successfully");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Could not take mysql backup");
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

I tried the above code but I couldn't get it done, keeps giving me

> CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>   error.

I have tried it by creating a .sql file on the location and still I get the same error.

Comment: Could it be that it fails to find mysqldump? Perhaps it's not in your path?

Comment: I think its similar to thread....  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376132/backup-mysql-database-java-code

Comment: I did that but now it causes the program to never stop. i.e. It starts, it does create a backup.sql file but it never stops! like an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the directory in which mysqldump resides into your path environment variable or use the full pathname I.e c:\directory\mysqldump

Comment: I did that but now it causes the program to never stop. i.e. It starts, it does create a backup.sql file but it never stops! like an infinite loop.

Comment: Are you sure it's just not waiting for the dump to finish? I would check the running processes to make sure it's done.

Comment: ok it was not that, I was experimenting with the string and left a space after the -p and caused the infinite error.

Comment: One more question why the backup from PHPmyadmin is like 3.5MB and from mysqldump only 27Kb? is there anything missing?

Comment: Thats not right, I'm not a mysql expert but the -r option in your command doesnt look right. Try replacing "-r" with ">".

Comment: I did this and it worked should I do something else?
 executeCmd = "C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysqldump -u" + dbUser + " -p" + dbPass + " --database " + dbName + " -r c:\\backup.sql";

Comment: Nope, checked the documentation and that looks good although you do not need to include the --database