# Backup mysql from remote database with mysqldump process error

Tags: java, mysql

I want to make  a backup of my remote mysql database. I have viewed many examples, but I can not find the answer what I am doing wrong. I have mysql server on my computer with other name than my remote database, just want to create sql file in my computer to have a copy.
My button action performed code is:

```
try {
            String cs = "jdbc:mysql://db4free.net:3306/DBNAME?user=DBUSER&password=DBPASSWORD";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection connection = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(cs);
            String executeCmd = "";
            if (connection != null) {
                executeCmd = "mysqldump -hwww.db4free.net -u DBUSER -pDBPASSWORD DBNAME > backup.sql";
                Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "cmd.exe", "/c", executeCmd });
                int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
                if (processComplete == 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "OK");
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Didn't make a copy.");
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Failed");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376132/backup-mysql-database-java-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system cannot find the file specified

Try adding path to the file

```
            executeCmd = "/usr/bin/mysqldump -hwww.db4free.net -u DBUSER -pDBPASSWORD DBNAME > backup.sql";
```

Comment: Nope, I get error - java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/mysqldump": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Where is mysqldump on your machine? Is it installed?

Comment: No. Is there any possibility to just make a *.sql file and not putt it into my local mysql server?

Comment: You must have mysqldump on the machine where this code is running. The code starts mysqldump-program

Comment: OK, let's I have checked my work PC and I have a working DB for my other older projects, but it throws me error, that I have mentioned in upper posts. I have checked my pat (echo %PATH%) and there is no path to mysql/bin. I have added it to Path. I updated my programm code above so now it shows me OK. But i do not see any changes in my local db. Why? Does my local db has to have the same name as remote one?

Comment: ADDITION. I have ran search and it found backup.sql file in my projects location. Thanks @Mikpa